# How to change color of image using Python?

Tags: python

I have a small gray image. I need to create many colored copies of this image (yellow one, green one, ...).

I don't need replace single color. My original image contains many shades of gray, and I need to create images with many shades of another colors.

How to do this using Python?

Comment: You can try the `PIL` or `Pillow`(a friendly `PIL` fork) module. Here is the document: https://pillow.readthedocs.org/

Comment: add some more information.

Answer (score 15):

I came across an article today on [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/news) that shows how to mix an image by a constant base color with an [affine transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation). The article is [Making thumbnails fast](http://engineering.khanacademy.org/posts/making-thumbnails-fast.htm) by William Chargin and its about improving image processing performance. The source code mentioned in it is at [affine transforms on PIL images](https://gist.github.com/WChargin/d8eb0cbafc4d4479d004).

Here is a demo starting with a greyscale [Lena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna) image resized to 231x231 pixels. This image was chosen because its "a standard test image widely used in the field of image processing since 1973".

```
from PIL import Image
from transforms import RGBTransform # from source code mentioned above

lena = Image.open("lena.png")
lena = lena.convert('RGB') # ensure image has 3 channels
lena
```

[image: starting image]

```
red = RGBTransform().mix_with((255, 0, 0),factor=.30).applied_to(lena)    
red
```

[image: red tinted image]

```
green = RGBTransform().mix_with((0, 255, 0),factor=.30).applied_to(lena)
green
```

[image: green tinted image]

```
blue = RGBTransform().mix_with((0, 0, 255),factor=.30).applied_to(lena)
blue
```

[image: blue tinted image]

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This might be overkill, but you could easily use functionalities from the OpenCV library (python bindings) to tint your gray scale images in color.

Try looking at these folks C++ code: http://answers.opencv.org/question/50781/false-coloring-of-grayscale-image/. Analogs the the functions that they use likely exist in the python library.

Here's a recommended course of action:

1. Convert the image to BGR (opencv convention lists red green blue
   in reverse order) from grayscale using cv2.cvtColor()
2. Apply an
   artificial color map of your choice (cv2.applyColorMap()) see:
   http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/colormaps.html