# i have a rgba image and i want to change the overall color

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, opencv

i have a image and i want to change the r g b values while preserving the alpha value . this is how to change the r g b value [How to change color of image using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32578346/how-to-change-color-of-image-using-python), but this does not keep the alpha chanel does anyone know how to do that

Comment: You need to change the relative intensity between the R, G, B channels. That doesn't affect the alpha channel. What exactly was the difficulty you encountered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the image into R, G, B and A channels, modify the RGB and put the original A channel back

```
from PIL import Image

# Load RGBA image
RGBA = Image.open('image.png')

# Split channels 
R, G, B, A = RGBA.split()

# Make an RGB to work on
RGB = Image.merge('RGB', (R, G, B))

... work on it ...

# Put original alpha back
RGB.putalpha(A)
```

Comment: thank you this is exactly want i wanted wish i had asked sooner would have saved me a couple hours besides the fact i am so grateful this is exactly what i neeeded